# Flag top 90% of rows in each partition of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below. I want to derive a column `Flag` such that approximately Top 90% of rows for each partition will have `TypeA` and remaining 10%
of rows will have `TypeB` as a flag in it.

```
+------+----+
| City | id |
+------+----+
| A    | 1A |
| A    | 2A |
| A    | 3A |
| A    | 4A |
| A    | 5A |
| B    | 1B |
| B    | 2B |
| B    | 3B |
| B    | 4B |
| B    | 5B |
| B    | 6B |
| D    | 1D |
| D    | 2D |
| D    | 3D |
| D    | 4D |
| D    | 5D |
| D    | 6D |
| D    | 7D |
| D    | 8D |
+------+----+
```

Desired Result

```
+------+----+-------+
| City | id | Flag  |
+------+----+-------+
| A    | 1A | TypeA |
| A    | 2A | TypeA |
| A    | 3A | TypeA |
| A    | 4A | TypeA | // Approximately Top 90% of rows for City A: Flag Type A
| A    | 5A | TypeB | // Approximately below 10% of rows for City A: Flag Type B
| B    | 1B | TypeA |
| B    | 2B | TypeA |
| B    | 3B | TypeA |
| B    | 4B | TypeA |// Approximately Top 90% of rows for City B: Flag Type A
| B    | 5B | TypeB |// Approximately below 10% of rows for City B: Flag Type B
| B    | 6B | TypeB |
| D    | 1D | TypeA |
| D    | 2D | TypeA |
| D    | 3D | TypeA |
| D    | 4D | TypeA |
| D    | 5D | TypeA |
| D    | 6D | TypeA |
| D    | 7D | TypeA |
| D    | 8D | TypeB |
+------+----+-------+
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db3d35/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to do explicit counting:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by city order by id) <=
                  0.9 * count(*) over (partition by city)
             then 'TypeA'
             else 'TypeB'
        end) as flag
from t
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !, appreciate your help .

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option, using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    City,
    id,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY id) /
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY City) <= 0.9
         THEN 'TypeA'
         ELSE 'TypeB' END AS Flag
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    City,
    Id;
```

[image]

### Demo

The first call to `COUNT` computes the number of elements in each city partition, up to the current row, as ordered by the `Id`.  Then, we normalize that by the total number of records for each city, and compare this to `0.9` to decide which flag to assign.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !, appreciate your help .

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server has a [percent_rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percent-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function for calculating the number you want directly, without needing to do it yourself:

```
SELECT City, id
     , CASE
        WHEN percent_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY id) <= 0.9 THEN 'TypeA'
        ELSE 'TypeB'
       END AS Flag
FROM table1
ORDER BY City, id;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db3d35/14).

Comment: Note that `PERCENT_RANK` is only available in SQL Server 2012 or later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !, appreciate your help .